# Command "InListPassiveTarget" of the PN532 device returns only one ACK and nothing else

Tags: nfc, mifare

I have managed to communicate with the PN532 device through a microcontroller (RS232). I get it out of the low power mode, I get the firmware version and the general status.

Now I want to read a MiFare type tag (ISO / IEC14443) and the frame I send is the following:

transmissionBuffer[0] = 0x00;

transmissionBuffer[1] = 0x00;

transmissionBuffer[2] = 0xFF;

transmissionBuffer[3] = 0x04;

transmissionBuffer[4] = 0xFC;

transmissionBuffer[5] = 0xD4;

transmissionBuffer[6] = 0x4A ;

transmissionBuffer[7] = 0x01;

transmissionBuffer[8] = 0x00;

transmissionBuffer[9] = 0xE1;

transmissionBuffer[10] = 0x00;

And the frame that the PN532 answers is:

receptionBuffer[0] = 0x00;

receptionBuffer[1] = 0x00;

receptionBuffer[2] = 0xFF;

receptionBuffer[3] = 0x00;

receptionBuffer[4] = 0xFF;

receptionBuffer[5] = 0x00;

I want to indicate that I perform a procedure in the reception of data from the MCU which consists of a timer that is reset every time a byte arrives from the PN532 and when no more bytes arrive, the timer overflows and it is assumed that the frame has arrived complete.

That way in a single package I get the ACK more the answer.

To rule out that the response to the "InListPassiveTarget" command takes more time than the timer, I have tried up to 20 seconds and only the ACK arrives for that command.

For the others that I mentioned at the beginning, there is no problem.

Beforehand I appreciate any suggestions or comments.

Thanks

Comment: To rule out a possible damage or error in the designed hardware, I performed the same test in a development kit and the results are the same.

Comment: In this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563378/how-do-i-read-passive-nfc-rfid-units-with-pn532/50155681#50155681

indicates that the frame to be sent is:

0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x00 0xff 0x04 0xFC 0xD4 0x4A 0x02 0x00 0xE0

But it does not meet the conditions to be valid since there is no response from PN532.